# How to interpret marginal effects when both DV and IVs are in fractional form?

Tags: regression, probit, marginal-effect

I ran a fractional probit model in which both IV and DV are in fractional form (i.e. proportions). Now I am having difficulty in interpreting the marginal effects (dydx). Suppose, the variable "proportions of young farmers" has a dy/dx value of 0.20, how would it be interpreted when the DV is "proportion of part-time farms"?

Is it like, "a 1-percent increase in the proportion of young farmers will result in 20% increase in the proportion of part-time farms" ?
If yes, this doesn't sound very natural. Please suggest.

Thanks
Abid

Comment: Can you clarify if 0.2 is some sort of marginal effect or the index function coefficient? Also, is the young farmer proportion in [0,1]?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov. Thanks. 0.21 is the marginal effect and young farmer proportion is between 0 and 1. (max:0.40, min:0.10)